# On form submit get LocalStorage Item and submit it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I'm trying to get a localStorage item and set a form's attribute but it doesn't seem to work which localStorage is used.

The localStorage item 'formitem' has value "somevalue".

This is what I currently have which doesn't work:

```
$(".form").submit(function() {
        if (localStorage.getItem("formitem") == "somevalue"){ 
            $(".form").attr('action', 'http://www.google.com')
        }else {$(".form").attr('action', 'http://www.bing.com')}
});
```

What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: Do either of your conditions work? Is the attribute set to bing.com, google.com, or neither?

Comment: Yes, but it searchers only for bing, no matter what 'formitem' value is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".form").submit(function() {
        if (parseInt(localStorage["formitem"]) == 1){ 
            $(".form").attr('action', 'http://www.google.com')
        }else {$(".form").attr('action', 'http://www.bing.com')}
});
```

Comment: Hi Shankar again. It seems that if I don't use brackets on 1 it doesn't work at all. And I do use brackets, it goes to bing instead when my 'formitem' value is 1.

Comment: Right okay. So it seems to working because of my fault of not being clear. When I said the value is "1", I didn't really mean 1. It is some text, which if I replace that text with 1 it doesn't work :/